# co authoring Excel cell highlight while another user editing same document

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, office-online-server

I am using SharePoint 2016 with Office online server. I have few excel document,  When I open excel document in web browser, Myself and my colleague both able to edit same excel document in same time. I can see his changes as soon as he completed , that's fine.  However, I would to like see which cell my colleague is working on, when i am in the same document. I do believe that In the right top corner, we can see co author user details along with which cell he is editing and also there is color indication in excel document when another user editing same document.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality isn't available with SharePoint Server + Office Online Server. This is available in SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Trevor. Per my knowledge, this is currently not supported in the OOS of SP 2016. The changes you see are not real-time, and the changes can only be seen after another user saves them.